# Appropriate data structure for 8 dimensional object

Tags: c++

I have an 8 dimensional array `xi`. For fixed indices `g_i, i=0..7` I have that `xi[g_0][g_1][g_2][g_3][g_4][g_5][g_6][g_7]` is of type `myObject`. How should I deal with such an Object?

My first idea was to define a multidimensional vector

```
vector< vector< vector< vector< vector< vector< vector< vector< myObject > > > > > > > > xi;
```

but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. A further complication is that the range of the indices depend on each other, e.g., the range of g_3 depends on the choice of g_0. I guess the 8d vector would give me the flexibility to deal with these dependencies. Are there any reasons (e.g. performance) against such an 8d vector?

Comment: What do you want to store? Points for example in 8 dimensions?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how the ranges depend on each other?

Comment: If things depend on each other you could use a tree where each layer represents a dimension.

Comment: No, myObject represents piecewise polynomials that are defined in a class that I wrote. Of course the range of the g_i is rather small (say 3-4 entries)

Comment: Concerning the dependencies: Let's say g_0, g_3 can be 0,1,2,3. If g_0=0 then g_3 can only be 0 and 1. if g_0>0, then g_3 can be 0,1,2,3.

Comment: @Alexander _'No, myObject represents piecewise polynomials'_ That doesn't require a _"multidimensional vector"_ of the same _dimension_ (or better _grade_?) of the polynomial formula for the possible results IMHO.